# WSO2 API, always return JSON without "Accept: application/json" header

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Using WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.6.0, is there a way to always return a JSON instead of an XML without adding a "Accept: Application/json" header?

I tried to add a node

```
<property description="output_content" name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
```

in the sequence, but with no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following property.

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: Why I couldn't find this property anywhere... Thanks

Comment: You can find this here - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/json-transform-mediator/#json-transform-mediator

Comment: What I meant was, "Why any amount of google-fu couldn't make me find that property"

Answer (score 1):

The property `ContentType` will take effect only with property `messageType`, so you need both like below:

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="ContentType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

This `messageType` property is responsible for used message formater on output.
You can read more in this WSO2 documentation [Property messageType](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-messageType)

Comment: Actually it seems that only messageType is needed to obtain a json. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Mewster - it depends on your requirement. The `messageType` is for setting out message formater, `ContentType` is for setting value of Content-Type HTTP header in response.